# PHP Code Sniffer - rule updates and tweaking for spaces and underscores

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer, phpcs

Before I start, I really don't want this to turn into a *"change your coding style"* post, but rather how I can use PHP Code Sniffer to "lint" our current coding standards. Thanks :)

There are two rules which, due to legacy and personal coding styles, we would wish to invert. Rather than just exclude, we want to ensure that the *opposite* is true.

We are currently using a config file, where the rules will go.

**No space after control**

We like to ensure that there is no space between the control signature and the bracket.

E.g.

```
if(condition)
```

Instead of

```
if (condition)
```

The current rule which flags this is `Squiz.ControlStructures.ControlSignature.SpaceAfterKeyword`.

Is there any way I can enforce the other way?

**Snake case class names**

We write our class names in `snake_case` not `camelCase`. This rule currently flags it up: `Squiz.Classes.ValidClassName.NotCamelCaps`

Again, any way we can alter this?

Struggling with the documentation.

Many thanks for your help

Comment: do you want to override the codesniffer rules or do you want tool that automatically add space?

Comment: We want the code sniffer to flag when there _is_ a space (as it shouldn't be there), so we can fix it

Comment: for that you can run the command. Do you know  command?

Comment: What command? :)

Comment: phpcs <parameter> <file or directory>

Comment: But what is the parameter for flagging when there is a space? As it only throws a warning when a space is missing

Comment: Also you can use phpcbf --standard=PSR2 <filepath> will fix the errors automatically

Comment: --standard=PSR2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172747/discussion-between-bhumi-shah-and-mikestreety).

Answer (score 0):

You might need to create custom sniff for that - check [Annotated-ruleset.xml](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Annotated-ruleset.xml) for external sniffs setting, and take a look at [Sniff](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/blob/master/src/Sniffs/Sniff.php) interface and some defined sniffs for clues.

Comment: Thanks @shudder, that is what I assumed. Will see if I can figure it out!